# MD1000 - PERC 6/E Adapter - Maximum RAID group

Tags: dell-perc, perc6

I can not find information on the maximum RAID that PERC 6 / E Adapter can handle.

We already have 2 RAID 5 of 5 HDD SAS, can I still add 5 HDD in RAID 5 (which will go up to 3 RAID 5 on the controller)? 
Without performance problem? 
the installation will be in production.

Thanks for the help.

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

answer by support Dell:

"The realization of this future configuration is quite possible.

When it comes to performance, when you add more disks and new concurrent accesses (generated by new LUNs) to existing accesses, performance changes are expected.

This point depends mainly on the use you make of it.

[Perc6e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xtuG.jpg)

"
Thanks for the help.

Jonathan